# Map a network drive

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the following code to map a network drive to my machine:

```
cmd = r"net use I: %s /P:YES" % network_path_toMyDrive
os.system("@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul") # I found that this line is important to refresh windows to show the new drive
os.system("@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul")
cmd = r"net use I: %s /P:YES" % selectIdriveChoices[I]
# call(cmd, shell=True)
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdin.write("y\n")
os.system("@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul")
os.system("@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul")
```

However, I can't provide a response when I am changing the drive while it is open:

```
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to I:.

Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]: 
System error 85 has occurred.

The local device name is already in use.
```

I just want to provide "y" if I see this message.

Comment: https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rogalski. I just don't want to over complicate it. All I need is to provide an answer to deleting the drive while it is open.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to force deleting the mapped drive if it was in use by adding /YES key to the command:

```
cmd = 'net use I: /D /YES'
```